# Arithmetic operation in php out ot string variable

Tags: php, variables, math, operation

I have a strange issue. I do this:

```
        $expdatek = explode(".",$datumk);
        $expdated = explode(".",$datumd);
        if($expdatek[2] == $expdated[2]){
            $monthk = intval(ltrim($expdatek[1], '0'));
            $monthd = intval(ltrim($expdated[1], '0'));
            $interval = $monthd - $monthk;
        }
```

The variable $datumk and $datumd came in a format like: "26.02.2016".
I try to proove if the year is the same, and if this happens, I just want to do the get difference between the two months.
For some reasone, I do not get any Output out of $interval. He just do not do the arithmetic operation. If I do an echo like: "echo $monthd" and "echo $monthk". He shows correctly the months without the leading zero, but he do not do the arithemic Operation.

Why?
I thought that PHP changes the format of a variable into that, what it needs for doing this operations. I learnd PHP by doing and it worked allways, ecept now. I don't figure it out.
Any hints?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/uRakb Please provide us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code was fine. The Problem was, that the variable was defined before in a function as a string. I redeclared it, but it still had some Problems obviously. Rename it, solved the problem. thx at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a date, try to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) library to perform the arithmetic operation. The method [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) calculates the difference between two dates:

```
$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , "27.03.2016");
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , "26.02.2016");

$diff = $date1->diff($date2 , true);

echo $diff->format("months: %m. Total days: %a");
```

A DateTime object can provide a [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.changelog):

```
$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , "26.02.2016");
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , "26.02.2016");

if ($date1 == $date2)
{
    echo 'they\'re equals';
}
```

If do you have any other validation which is needed between both date, can you [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , "26.02.2016");
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , "26.02.2016");

if ($date1->format("m") == $date2->format("m"))
{
    echo 'the months are equals';
}
```

So, if you need do some calc:

```
$expdatek = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , $datumk);
$expdated = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y" , $datumd);

if($expdatek->format('Y') == $expdated->format('Y')){
    $interval = $expdatek->diff($expdated , true);

    var_dump($interval);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! ... I need, my type of operations, because I do not want to know only the exact month-differences.
Where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: @SergiuLongodor my answer works as you described in your question. Both scripts can be modified and replaced as well.

Comment: @SergiuLongodor seems to have no mistake. But, DateTime is recommended to perform any Date (or time) arithmetic operation.

Comment: Thank you! I know, I could use this,... hmmm. I have to rewrite the script, and the script works one time, and one other time not... is where any thing I do not know about arithmetic oprations in PHP?

Comment: There's no problem at all, but a cast type (to int) is better to read (and work as well) than `ltrim` + `intval`. So, your code should be something like this `$monthk = (int)$expdatek[1];`

Comment: The Code was fine. The Problem was, that the variable was defined before in a function as a string. I redeclared it, but it still had some Problems obviously. Rename it, solved the problem. thx at all.